# Filtering multiple columns Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a method which takes a pandas dataframe as an input:

```
def dfColumnFilter(df, columnFilter, columnName):
    ''' Returns a filtered DataFrame

    Keyword arguments: 
    df           :  DataFrame in which to apply the filter
    columnFilter :  The list of which to filter by
    columnName   :  The DataFrame column to apply the columnFilter to '''

    for column_filter in columnFilter:
        df=df[df[columnName] == column_filter]
        return df
```

**The question is is how do I make this work for n columns?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`*args`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs) keyword to pass a list of pairs:

```
def filter_df(df, *args):
    for k, v in args:
        df = df[df[k] == v]
    return df
```

It can be used like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 1, 1], 'b': [1, 3, 3, 3]})

>>> filter_df(df, ('a', 1), ('b', 2))
    a   b
2   1   3
3   1   3
```

**Note**

In theory, you could use `**kwargs`, which would have a more pleasing usage:

```
filter_df(df, a=1, b=2)
```

but then you could only use it for columns whose names are valid Python identifiers.

**Edit**

See comment below by @Goyo for a better implementation point.

Comment: I think you can use the dictionary syntax for invalid identifiers:<br>

df = pd.DataFrame({'first one': [1, 2, 1, 1], 'second one': [1, 3, 3, 3]})<br>

filter_df(df, {'first one'=1, 'second one'=2})

Answer (score 1):

You can use as below

```py
filtered_df = df[(df[column1]=='foo') & (df[column2]=='bar')]
```

and you can continue with `&` and parentesis statements.