# Pandas: Filter by values within multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I'm trying to filter a dataframe based on the values within the multiple columns, based on a single condition, but keep other columns to which I don't want to apply the filter at all.

I've reviewed these answers, with the third being the closest, but still no luck:

- [how do you filter pandas dataframes by multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22086116/how-do-you-filter-pandas-dataframes-by-multiple-columns)
- [Filtering multiple columns Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35131096/filtering-multiple-columns-pandas)
- [Python Pandas - How to filter multiple columns by one value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42711186/python-pandas-how-to-filter-multiple-columns-by-one-value)

**Setup:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'month':[1,1,1,2,2],
        'a':['A','A','A','A','NONE'],
        'b':['B','B','B','B','B'],
        'c':['C','C','C','NONE','NONE']
    }, columns = ['month','a','b','c'])

l = ['month','a','c']
df = df.loc[df['month'] == df['month'].max(), df.columns.isin(l)].reset_index(drop = True)
```

**Current Output:**

```
   month     a     c
0      2     A  NONE
1      2  NONE  NONE
```

**Desired Output:**

```
   month     a
0      2     A
1      2  NONE
```

I've tried:

```
sub = l[1:]
df = df[(df.loc[:, sub] != 'NONE').any(axis = 1)]
```

and many other variations (`.all()`, `[sub, :]`, `~df.loc[...]`, `(axis = 0)`), but all with no luck.

Basically I want to drop any column (within the `sub` list) that has all 'NONE' values in it.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first want to substitute your `'NONE'` with `np.nan` so that it is recognized as a null value by `dropna`.  Then use `loc` with your boolean series and column subset.  Then use `dropna` with `axis=1` and `how='all'`

```
df.replace('NONE', np.nan) \
    .loc[df.month == df.month.max(), l].dropna(axis=1, how='all')

   month     a
3      2     A
4      2  NONE
```

Comment: So everything before the "Current Output" part I'm happy with.  In reality the `l = []` would be much longer than a few entries, and `sub` would simply be `l` minus the first couple entries.  It's filtering for the 'NONE' values within the columns, not the column names themselves, that I'm having issues with.

Comment: Just added a little more color in my question: "Basically I want to drop any column (within the `sub` list) that has all 'NONE' values in it."

Comment: Awesome, that killed two birds with one stone.  Thank you sir.