# How can I select the rows which contains some specific value in a dataframe using python?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am quite new to python and coding, so sorry in advance if I may not be so clear.
I have a dataframe where the rows correspond to IDs (f.ied) and the columns to several values (ICD10 codes). I want to select the rows which contain specific ICD10 codes.
However, I could not find the right way to do so...I tried with loc and set but no luck...any help, please?

The dataframe is like that:

each rows corresponds to f.ied (IDs). I want to know which f.ied have specific codes: I20, I21, I22, I23, I24, I25.

[image: Dataframe]

Comment: Welcome! does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/44416069/6692898

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select rows from a DataFrame based on column values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-to-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values)

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'feid': [2, 4, 8, 0],
                    'f42002': [2, 0, 0, 0],
                    'f42003': [10, 'I21', 1, 'J10']})

df = df.set_index('feid')
df
```

DataFrame

```
    f42002  f42003
feid        
2   2   10
4   0   I21
8   0   1
0   0   J10
```

Desired items

```
mylist = ['I21', 'J10']

for i in mylist:
  print(df[(df['f42002']==i) | (df['f42003']==i)].index.values)
```

Result:

```
[4]
[0]
```